# Bounds of integration in nonlinear first order ODE solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The solution to a 1st order nonlinear ODE is as follows:

$y=e^{\tan^{-1}{x}}(A+\int^xe^{-(tan^{-1}a)/3}\frac{a}{3}da)^3$

Applying boundary condition: $y(0) = 1$

We get 
$y=e^{\tan^{-1}{x}}(1+\int_0^xe^{-(tan^{-1}a)/3}\frac{a}{3}da)^3$

Could someone please explain the intermediate steps. The integral is impossible to evaluate and I dont understand how we can just magically change the integration bounds and change the coefficient to 1 and call it quits....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's put in an explicit lower bound $c$ and try to satisfy the boundary condition.

$$y(0)=(A+\int^0_ce^{-(tan^{-1}a)/3}\frac{a}{3}da)^3=1$$

$$\implies A+\int^0_ce^{-(tan^{-1}a)/3}\frac{a}{3}da =1$$

we have 2 arbitrary parameters $A$ and $c$ to satisfy this one condition. The parameters are not independent , they must satisfy 
$$\implies A=1-\int^0_ce^{-(tan^{-1}a)/3}\frac{a}{3}da$$

which has an infinite number of solutions, but one obvious one is to make the integral vanish by setting $c=0$ so that $A=1$